# Spotify not working in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, spotify

when I try to launch Spotify it doesn't work nothing happens no errors nothing it's like i never even tried to launch it
I tried installing using apt but that didn't work so I installed using snap

Comment: Happens for me too, `(spotify:78058): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:05:43.269: cannot open display: :1`

Comment: Working for me now, might be related to Wayland vs X (I switched to X at some point), but I don't recall if A came before B.

Comment: For me switching back to X instead of Wayland worked.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved apparently it didn't support ubuntu 22.04 re-installed it works fine